# Copy Files from one server to another using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to copy files from one server to another using Ansible. 
Below is the example

```
Server A ------> Server B
Server C ------> Server D
```

I have my one file on Server A and specifically want to copy that file on to the server B, and same for server C to D. Folder to save files to the destination is the same. I can do it for 2 or 3 hosts. But how can I create dynamically for let us say 100 nodes to copy particular single file assign to desired server only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`fetch`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html) and [`copy`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) to do this.

Assuming an inventory that was structured something like this:

```
[source-servers]
ServerA
ServerC

[dest-servers]
ServerB source-server=ServerA
ServerD source-server=ServerB
```

And then ran the following `fetch` task:

```
- name: fetch file from source servers
  hosts: source-servers
  fetch:
    src: /path/to/file
    dest: /tmp
```

Would copy the file `/path/to/file` on ServerA to the Ansible control host under `/tmp/ServerA/path/to/file` and `/path/to/file` on ServerB to the Ansible control host under `/tmp/ServerB/path/to/file`

From here we just then need to make sure that each of the `dest-servers` has a variable defined that says what server(s) it is paired with under a host var either in a separate host vars file or [in line in the inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#host-variables) as above.

And then we can put the right file on the right `dest-server` with this `copy` task:

```
- name: copy the paired files to the right servers
  hosts: dest-servers
  copy:
    src: "/tmp/{{ source-server }}/path/to/file"
    dest: /path/to/dest
```

Comment: Hi @MahelaRanawat if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.